# PHP preg_match_all regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

If I have a string like: `10/10/12/12`

I'm using:

```
$string = '10/10/12/12';
preg_match_all('/[0-9]+\/[0-9]+/', $string, $results);
```

This only seems to match `10/10`, and `12/12`. I also want to match `10/12`. Is it because after the `10/10` is matched that is removed from the picture? So after the first match it'll only match things from `/12/12`?

If I want to match all `10/10`, `10/12`, `12/12`, what should my regex look like? Thanks.

Edit: I did this

```
$arr = explode('/', $string);
$count = count($arr) - 1;
$newarr = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
{
    $newarr[] = $arr[$i].'/'.$arr[$i+1];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd advise not using regular expression. Instead you could for example first split on slash using `explode`. Then iterate over the parts, checking for two consecutive parts which both consist of only digits.

---

The reason why your regular expression doesn't work is because the match consumes the characters it matches. Searching for the next match starts from just after where the previous match ended.

If you really want to use regular expressions you can use a zero-width match such as a lookahead to avoid consuming the characters, and put a capturing match inside the lookahead.

```
'#[0-9]+/(?=([0-9]+))#'
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/7LS0J)

Comment: Thanks, I edited my post to show how I did it now. Is that what you meant? Seems to work.

Comment: @Joker: Yes. You didn't check if the parts are digits, but if you can assume they are then your code seems OK to me.

Comment: ATM it should be okay to avoid the digit check, but may consider doing it later just in case, thanks for showing the alternative regex too.

Comment: @Joker: I'm actually surprised that putting a capturing group inside a non-capturing group works. I learned something new, so thanks for the interesting question. :)